# How to enter email address as object in Protégé?

Tags: owl, mailto, protege

When using OWL, it's useful to declare a property for personal email as `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty` as it is for `foaf:mbox`. While using OWL Full that could be done for datatype properties, in OWL DL, it needs to be an object property as object and datatype properties are disjoint there. Yet, most tools have no issue with that.

Now I need to use Protégé to prepare an exercise. It doesn't allow to declare a datatype property `owl:InverseFunctionalProperty` and it doesn't allow to have email address as object of an abject property. When encoded externally, as expected, Protégé treats it as annotation property.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Declare `foaf:mbox` as a datatype property and use [OWL 2 keys](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Keys).

**Option 2**

Define the `mailto` prefix as `mailto:` (i. e. `@prefix mailto: <mailto:> .`) on the "Ontology prefixes" tab.

Then type `mailto:me@example.org` in the "Create a new OWLNamedIndividual" dialog.

Without such definition, Protégé doesn't process `mailto:me@example.org` correctly, allowing to type `mailto://me@example.org` only.

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 would not work in my case as it uses an axiom which is not included in the course and if it will be, it would be much further. Option 2 is a bit clumsy, compered to TBC for example, but if there is no other way in Protégé, I'll go with it.